# Get Dropdown selected value using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I use the following code to get the selected value of my dropdown using JQuery.

```
pStartMonth = $('#cboMonth1').val();
```

But I get the result as `undefined`. What am I missing?

The HTML for my dropdown:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboMonth1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;" ValidationGroup="vTimeSlot">
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">January</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="2">February</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="4">April</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="5">May</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="6">June</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="7">July</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="8">August</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="9">September</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="10">October</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="11">November</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="12">December</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Please post up your HTML. I'm unable to replicate this. http://jsfiddle.net/LvsGr/

Comment: Also please post all of your jQuery/Javascript code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`id` attributes of ASP.Net controls are generated server-side, so in your generated HTML, the `id` would actually be something like `_$ctrl0239023930`. What you need to use is `ClientID` like this:

```
pStartMonth = $('#<%= cboMonth1.ClientID %>').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement you have seems perfectly alright. you might be missing one or more of the following.

- Include jQuery library
- Put code in docuemt.ready
- Ensure you

**Edit** Based on updated OP, as you have asp.net dropdown the id of dropdown will be changed in generated html so you need to use ClientID. You can also set [**ClientIDMode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to `static` to generate the same id as you have in server control.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   pStartMonth = $('#<%= cboMonth1.ClientID %>').val();
   alert(pStartMonth );
});
```

#### ClientIDMode

> ASP.NET provides multiple algorithms for how to generate the ClientID
>   property value. You select which algorithm to use for a control by
>   setting its ClientIDMode property. The algorithms are identified by
>   the ClientIDMode enumeration values that are listed in the following
>   table, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx).

You can use the server side `id` in javascript by setting *ClientIDMode = "static"*

*HTML*

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboMonth1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" AutoPostBack="true" onclick="javascript:shouldsubmit=false;" ValidationGroup="vTimeSlot">
```

*Javascript*

```
pStartMonth = $('#cboMonth1').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the javascript function is in .js file then use:

```
    $('select[id$="cboMonth1"]').val();
```

If it is in .aspx file than use:

```
    $('#<%= cboMonth1.ClientID %>').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#cboMonth1 option:selected").val();
```

Comment: This is no different to what the OP has now.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is in a file that is not parsed as ASP.Net (such as an included JS file), you can reference the element like this...

```
pStartMonth = $('[id$=cboMonth1]').val();
```

That will find an element with an ID that *ends with* `cboMonth1`, which yours will.