# get dropdownlist selected value and send to pop up

Tags: javascript

This is dropdownlist :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

this is edit-category button :

```
<span class="btn btn-default edit-category" data-id="what to store here to get selected item text from dropdownlist">Edit Category</span>
```

this is my js :

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-category", function () {
       //show pop-up div
        $('.pop-up-category').addClass('show-popup');


//get dropdownlist selected value
var clicked = $(this);
 var id = clicked.attr("data-id");

       //put taken value here
        $('.edit-form .edit-form-label[data-name="category-id"] input').attr('value', id);
    });
```

Any idea how to get Selected item value or text from dropdownlist ??

Comment: I think this should be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243368/get-dropdown-selected-value-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a change event as opposed to click
         $("select.category").change(function(){
         $("#category_input").attr("value",
                $(this).value());
          )};

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

**This is the right method to get an id and selectedtext from DropDownList.**

> //gets id from the dropdownlist populated from database, so id here is a
>   column in a table in the database because dropdownlist populates using
>   database connection*

```
var id = $("#DropDownList1 option:selected").val();
```

> //gets selected text from dropdownlist

```
var txt= $("#DropDownList1 option:selected").text();
```

Tested and working !!

Hope this solution will be useful for others ...